# Accessing Database on Host network from docker web container on overlay network

Tags: docker

I have a network 10.0.0.0/24 with 1 Oracle db-host01 ip address 10.0.0.100 and  2 docker hosts Docker01 10.0.0.15 and Docker02 10.0.0.16 and swarm is configured. I have configured  a overlay network "overnet" with network address 192.168.6.0/24.

I have executed the below cmd to run a web container on overlay network.

docker run -i -t -d -p 9090:6000 --name portal --network overnet portal:1.0

but the web container is ip address 192.168.6.2 is not communicating with Oracale DB 10.0.0.100.

I can ping DB ip 10.0.0.100 from web container.

how I can make communication possible and can run this container as service as well.

regards
Sohail

Answer (score 0):

Overlay networks are not attachable by default, which means that standalone containers cannot use them.

You can specify that a network should be attachable using the `--attachable` flag, such as

```
$ docker network create -d overlay --attachable overnet
```

If you are unable to modify the network, create a service for your container using

```
docker service create --network overnet --publish 9090:6000 --name portal portal:1.0
```

at which point it will be able to use the overlay network.

Comment: I did the same as you are suggesting. but my question is how can I reach web container from DB server